# Superlance crashmail doesn't send email with custom mail program

Tags: supervisord

I have supervisor running a program and when the program crashes, I would like crashmail to send me an email. I've created my own binary which sends mail and I would like crashmail to use this. If I run the binary standalone from my server, it sends me an email.

I kill the process with the PID but no email's are sent.

Here is my configuration:

```
[eventlistener:crashmail]
command=crashmail -a -m dev@example.com -s /usr/local/bin/mailer
stdout_logfile = /var/www/services/crashmail.log
events=PROCESS_STATE_EXITED, PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED, PROCESS_STATE_STOPPING
```

My binary does not accept anything from STDIN as the emails to send notifications to are hard coded. Is this affecting crashmail?

Comment: Does your binary run other programs? I'm wondering if your binary is assuming something about your environment ($PATH, $HOME, etc) that is true when you log in but not true when crashmail runs it.

Comment: Nope, the binary just makes an HTTP resquest. It's self-contained

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to get crashmail to work, so here are two solutions I tried.

1. Monitoring the supervisor process with a node based event listener

[supervisord-eventlistener](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supervisord-eventlistener)

Here is the configuration:

```
    [eventlistener:monitoring]
    command = /usr/bin/nodejs /etc/supervisor/monitoring.js
    events = PROCESS_STATE,PROCESS_COMMUNICATION,SUPERVISOR_STATE_CHANGE
```

From the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supervisord-eventlistener), you can listen for any event and send an email within that function callback.

2. Since the service that needs to be monitored is a web service. I use cron to check the site periodically; if a non-200 response code is returned, send an email within the bash script you're checking the response code with.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   httpCode=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" siteUrl)

   if [ $httpCode -eq "200" ]
   then
       echo "OK"
   else
       //send email
   fi
   ```

Ref: [get response code curl command](https://superuser.com/questions/272265/getting-curl-to-output-http-status-code)